# how to move from ViewController in iOS to Shared Page in Portable class library folder xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, cross-platform

I have a view controller and a button in it, on clicking that button ,I want to move to Shared Page in my Portable class library folder?? Application is getting crashed on the Button click.

```
  partial void UIButton75_TouchUpInside(UIButton sender)
    {
        var secondViewController = App.GetSecondPage().CreateViewController();
        NavigationController.PushViewController(secondViewController, true);
    }
```

GetSecondPage() is a method in our App.cs in Portable folder,which directs to the Shared Page.

```
 public static Page GetSecondPage()
    {
        var formsPage = new NavigationPage(new HomePage());

        return formsPage;
    }
```

Comment: what's the code in CreateViewController?

Comment: I guess it is the inbuilt method used in iOS

Comment: What is the exception throw when you have crash? Do your ViewController wrap in a UINavigationController?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to use Xamarin Forms with custom design elements on specific platforms. Design all you pages in Forms (in portable project) and customize the elements for platform specific using renderers.

Or is there a specific issue you want to solve with the view controller (from ios) that a page in forms cannot do?

If so, load the (portable) application (app from portable) where you need it, not necessarily in FinishLauching method of AppDelegate cs